# In Paramiko, execute commands from a list or dict and save the result to a list or dict

Tags: python, dictionary, ssh, paramiko

In Paramiko, how to pass a list or dict to `exec_command` and save results to a list or dict?

1. I need `sleep` between exec_command.
2. Commands are not executed sequentially, but in the order of 1, 2, 1.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(d.values()[0])

reuslt1 = stdout.read()

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(d.values()[1])

reuslt2 = stdout.read()

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(d.values()[0])

reuslt3 = stdout.read()
```

If there are no two problems mentioned above, I have tried `map()`, it works fine.

```
cmd = ['xxx', 'xxx']

def func(cmd):
    stdin, stdout, stderr= ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    result = stdout.read()
    return result

list(map(func, cmd))
```

My problem is that I need to SSH a remote Linux, replace a string in a file.

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(ip, port, username, password)

command = {
    "search" : "grep$img_name ='string' file",
    "modify" : "sed -i 's/$img_name = $now/$img_name = $word/g' file",
}

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command.values()[0])
before = stdout.read()
sleep(1)    ##If I don't add the wait, I will grep the string twice before the modification.
ssh.exec_command(command.values()[1])
sleep(1)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command.values()[0])
after = stdout.read()    ##Confirm that my modification was successful
ssh.close()
```

I don't want to repeat coding `stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command()`.

Comment: what are you even trying to do? I understand nothing at all.. Please elaborate so that, other users can understand and help you out.

Comment: If you have a new problem post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this: [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3294889/850848).

So in Python 3:

```
for key, value in command.items():
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(value)
    results[key] = stdout.read()
```

---

Regarding the `sleep`: The `stdout.read()` not only reads a command output. It, as an side effect of reading the output, waits for the command to finish. As you do not call `stdout.read()` for the `sed`, you do not wait for it to finish. So actually, the `for` loop above should solve that problem too, as it waits for all commands, including the `sed`, to finish.

Comment: Thank you for modifying the question, great. I tried your suggestion. But, Do you mean that I don't need to check if it is changed after the modification?

Comment: I didn't wrote that. If you want to repeat the `grep`, add a third entry to the `command` dictionary.